# Split with RegExp group

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace word `WUB` from any string which can contain many `WUB` words following together.
Example:
`WUBHelloWUBWUBitsWUBmeWUB` must become `Hello its me`

I decided to use split with RegExp:

`'WUBHelloWUBWUBitsWUBmeWUB'.split(/(WUB)+/g).join(" ").split(/\s{2,}/g).join(" ").trim()`

But when i'm using roud brakets `(WUB)+`  to match `WUB` from 1 to unlimited times - it doesn't work.

Comment: Make it non-capturing `(?:WUB)+`

Comment: Split is ridiculous. It creates an array of pointers from which to construct a list (array). Join takes the array and catenaets them together. Regex replace just creates the array of pointers from  which to construct an new string. Might as well just replace all `(?:WUB)+` with nothing since it is about 300 times faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split()` function includes capturing groups in result set to avoid this behavior you have to use non-capturing groups:

```
(?:WUB)+
```

You don't need `split()` even:

```
'WUBHelloWUBWUBitsWUBmeWUB'.replace(/(?:WUB)+/g, " ").trim();
```

Comment: `/WUB/g` is enough

Comment: No, it will produce more than one space character between other words.